# Set the title of navigation bar based on props

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How do I set the title of the navigation bar based on props, I want to do something like below.

```
static navigationOptions = {
title: this.props.navigation.state.params.name,
```

};

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override `navigationOptions` in the route config to do that for you:

```
// Optional: Override the `navigationOptions` for the screen
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: `${navigation.state.params.name}'s Profile'`,
})
```

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#routeconfigs